# azcopy between digitalocean and azure

Tags: azure, digital-ocean-spaces

I want to copy files from digitalocean into azure storage, I used this command :

```
sudo azcopy copy "https://myspace.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com" "https://myspace.blob.core.windows.net/myspace" --recursive
```

am getting this error :

```
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: failed to scan path /home/mypc/https:/myspace.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com due to stat /home/mypc/https:/myspace.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com: no such file or directory.
```

Comment: 1. Check if there is any typo in the path or permission issue. 2. See the logs using cmdlet `azcopy copy "[source_path]" "[destination path]" --log-level=info --recursive`

Answer (score 0):

I used [Azure data factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-hello-world-copy-data-tool), it helped me out.